# Use another font in PDFBundle (PHPPdf)

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I use the PdfBundle (PHPPdf) in Symfony2 and want to use another font.
I want to add the font.xml file to the config.yml in the app folder:

```
ps_pdf:
    fonts_file: "@FoundationBundle/Resources/config/fonts.xml"
```

But it say always `File "@FoundationBundle/Resources/config/fonts.xml" doesn't exist or is unreadable` I try different variations but I don't find a solution. How I can load the fonts.xml File?

Edit: My path to the fonts.xml is `/src/FoundationBundle/Resources/config/fonts.xml` so I want to load this in the `/app/config/config.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hvae noticed the typo in the directory named `Recources`. It should be `Resources`.

Apart from that, if I remember correctly, this bundle does not support "bundle syntax". Try using this instead:

```
ps_pdf:
    fonts_file: "%kernel_root%/Resources/config/fonts.xml"
```

Put your `fonts.xml` into `/path/to/your/project/app/Resources/config/`

Comment: I'm not sure about the %kernel_root% but the help that I can't use the bundle syntax helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following syntax for load the xml File in my Foundation Bundle (Add the lines in the `app/config/config.yml`):

```
ps_pdf:
    fonts_file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/FoundationBundle/Resources/config/fonts.xml"
```

Important for me is that I need to clear the cache in symfony so that it works with `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`. I also need to copy the fonts.xml content from `/vendor/psliwa/php-pdf/lib/PHPPdf/Resourced/config/fonts.xml` in the new `fonts.xml` config.

The next problem was to set the variables in the `font.xml` in my Bundle. Here I can use the Bundle Syntax again. So I set the `calibri` font like this in the font XML:

```
<font name="calibri">
    <normal src="%FoundationBundle:public/fonts/calibri.ttf%" />
    <bold src="%FoundationBundle:public/fonts/calibrib.ttf%" />
    <italic src="%FoundationBundle:public/fonts/calibrii.ttf%" />
    <bold-italic src="%FoundationBundle:public/fonts/calibribi.ttf%" />
</font>
```

Now the font is in the Foundation Bundle under `Resources/public/fonts`. The fonts I saved in the Foundation Bundle in the folder `Resources/public/fonts`.

After changing the `font.xml` there is also a cache clear required. Also in the developer environmental (`php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`)